# My application stops after first activity. It should go to second and then to third activity

Tags: java, android

My application stops after first activity. It should go to second and then to third activity.

But if I remove the code from Button GoToAP; then the app runs smoothly.

Please guide me how to go from second activity to third activity.

THANKS FOR ALL THE RESPONSES.

```
  public class sem1 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sem1);

}


Button GoToAP;

protected void onStart() {
    GoToAP = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);

    GoToAP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(sem1.this, sem1a.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });


}
```

}

Comment: what happens if you remove sem1.this and just use this? And what do you mean by my application stops. Does it crash?

Comment: I guess you haven´t registrated the new activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

Call super.start() on your onStart() method like this:->

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    GoToAP = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);

    GoToAP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(sem1.this, sem1a.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });


}
```

Hope it will work. Else, check that you have added your activity in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a button with `button11` ID in your `sem1` layout file.

You should register your activity in Android Manifest file like this:

```
<application>
    ...
    <activity android:name=".sem1a" />
    ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Be sure you are added this in you manifist.xml**
`<application>
    ...
    <activity android:name=".sem1a" />
    ...
</application>`

**Be sure you are not using the same layout xml with two activities.**

**Be sure of all used component is initialized and mapped with it's second activity**